# Log into MYSQL as root

Tags: mysql, xampp, root

I'm trying to log in to MySQL as root on macOS. I tried using this command line:

```
[mysql -u root -p][1]
```

This is how it turned out. It shows an arrow and blank space. Is there anything I can do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I think removing the square brackets should fix the problem.

```
mysql -u root -p
```

Hit enter at the password prompt.